# Replace an object with a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dictionary like so:

```
test_dict = {1.0: 0, 3.0: 2}
```

and I want to replace an object with it like so:

```
a = 1.0

 for k, v in test_dict.iteritems():
    if a == k:
        a = v
```

Is there a better way to do this without loops or a one liner?

I have also tried `a = a.map(test_dict)` but that doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: a = test_dict[a] - or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting  `test_dict[a]` to be, but that returns a key error anyway.  I want to replace the values of objects with a dictionary is all

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that "a" might be absent from the dictionary in your use case. Yes, in that case you'll get a key error, and zwer's answer handles that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be reduced to:

```
a = 1.0
a = test_dict.get(a, a)
```

or if you need an explicit check (for some additional processing):

```
a = 1.0
if a in test_dict:
    a = test_dict[a]
```